# How to get an HTML comment with PowerShell

Tags: html, powershell, comments

If I have a comment in HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>

      <!-- some comment1 -->  

    </body>
</html>
<!-- some comment2 -->
```

How can I get it with PowerShell?

I tried to test it on some website:
[image]

So I used:

```
$url = "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp" 
$webrequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url 
$webrequest.ParsedHtml.body.innerHTML
```

But `$webrequest.ParsedHtml.body.innerHTML` is a string and I don't know how to get the comment or just list all the comment on the website.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/17/using-the-split-method-in-powershell/

Comment: @mplungjan `$webrequest.ParsedHtml.body.innerHTML.Split("<!--")` also did the job, thanks. I didn't want to use string manipulation because I thought maybe there is something built-in already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about getting the `[if IE]` type comments as they are special notation (i.e. not *just* a comment).

However to get the others you can filter on the `tagName`

```
$url = "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp" 
$webrequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url
$webrequest.AllElements | Where-Object tagName -eq "!"
```

Results:

```
innerHTML : 
innerText : 
outerHTML : 
outerText : 
tagName   : !

innerHTML : <!-- MainLeaderboard-->
innerText : 
outerHTML : <!-- MainLeaderboard-->
outerText : 
tagName   : !

innerHTML : <!-- BottomMediumRectangle -->
innerText : 
outerHTML : <!-- BottomMediumRectangle -->
outerText : 
tagName   : !

innerHTML : <!-- RightBottomMediumRectangle -->
innerText : 
outerHTML : <!-- RightBottomMediumRectangle -->
outerText : 
tagName   : !
```

Comment: This did the job, nice. I will mark it as answer later.